# exponential bound for sum of geometric variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am writing my bachelor thesis and I am using the book "Brownian motion" by Mörters and Perez. I have troubles with the following lemma:

Let $X_j$, $j \in \mathbb{N}$, geometrically distributed on $\{1,2,...\}$ with mean $2$. For $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $k \leqslant m$ the following inequality holds.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\{|\sum_{j=1}^k (X_j-2)| \geqslant \epsilon m\}\right) \leqslant 4 \exp\{-\tfrac{1}{5} \epsilon^2 m\}
\end{align*}

I already showed, using the hints in the book, (without Hoeffdings inequality) the inequality

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\{\sum_{j=1}^k (X_j-2) \geqslant \epsilon m\}\right) \leqslant  \exp\{-\tfrac{1}{5} \epsilon^2 m\}
\end{align*}

Now I want to proof the other part of the inequality via the one I already showed. In his book he states that it is obvious. I cannot see that and my endless computation did not really lead anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the same proof to $-\sum_{j=1}^k (X_j-2)$ and notice that
$$
\mathsf{E}e^{-\lambda(X_j-2)}=\frac{e^{2\lambda}}{2e^\lambda-1}\le 1+\lambda^2\le e^{\lambda^2}.
$$